# OSGI Component Satisfied, Still Not Being Activated

Tags: java, osgi, kura

I have an unsatisfied OSGI component, which seems to tell me that it is satisfied...

If I type `ls` the result is the following:

```
26  Active org.eclipse.kura.watchdog.WatchdogService org.eclipse.kura.linux.watchdog(bid=63)
82  Active com.company.product.dependencybucketimpl.DependencyBucketImpl            com.company.product.dependencybucketimpl(bid=122)
83  Unsatisfied com.company.product.statemachineXXXXimpl.StateMachineXXXXImpl com.company.product.statemachineXXXXimpl(bid=123)
```

There are several other bundles but these are the relevant ones.

When I try to look at the `Unsatisfied` bundle specifically, it seems that the two bundles which are referenced have been activated successfully.

```
osgi> ls -c 123
Components in bundle com.company.product.statemachineXXXXimpl:
ID  Component details
83  Component[
    name = com.company.product.statemachineXXXXimpl.StateMachineXXXXImpl
    activate = activate
    deactivate = deactivate
    modified = modified
    configuration-policy = optional
    factory = null
    autoenable = true
    immediate = true
    implementation = com.company.product.statemachineXXXXimpl.StateMachineXXXXImpl
    state = Unsatisfied
    properties = {service.pid=com.company.product.statemachineXXXXimpl.StateMachineXXXXImpl}
    serviceFactory = false
    serviceInterface = [com.company.product.common.PayloadReadyNotifier, com.company.product.common.StateMachineXXXX]
    references = {
        Reference[name = WatchdogService, interface = org.eclipse.kura.watchdog.WatchdogService, policy = static, cardinality = 1..1, target = null, bind = setWatchdogService, unbind = unsetWatchdogService]
        Reference[name = DependencyBucket, interface = com.company.product.common.DependencyBucket, policy = static, cardinality = 1..1, target = null, bind = setDependencyBucket, unbind = unsetDependencyBucket]
    }
    located in bundle = com.company.product.statemachineXXXXimpl_1.0.0.dev [123]
]
Dynamic information :
  The component is satisfied
  All component references are satisfied
  Component configurations :
    Configuration properties:
      logStateMachineTransitions = true
      objectClass = String[com.company.product.common.PayloadReadyNotifier,com.company.product.common.StateMachineXXXX]
      kura.service.pid = com.company.product.statemachineXXXXimpl.StateMachineXXXXImpl
      service.pid = com.company.product.statemachineXXXXimpl.StateMachineXXXXImpl
      systemIdleTimeout = 600
      ChargerDischargeTimeout = 300
      component.name = com.company.product.statemachineXXXXimpl.StateMachineXXXXImpl
      component.id = 178
    Instances:
```

Here is the .xml in the definition for the bundle in question:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<component xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/scr/v1.1.0"
           name="com.company.product.statemachineXXXXimpl.StateMachineXXXXImpl"
           activate="activate"
           configuration-policy="optional"
           deactivate="deactivate"
           enabled="true"
           immediate="true"
           modified="modified">

    <implementation class="com.company.product.statemachineXXXXimpl.StateMachineXXXXImpl"/>

    <property name="service.pid"
              type="String"
              value="com.company.product.statemachineXXXXimpl.StateMachineXXXXImpl"/>

    <reference name="WatchdogService"
               bind="setWatchdogService"
               unbind="unsetWatchdogService"
               interface="org.eclipse.kura.watchdog.WatchdogService"
               cardinality="1..1"
               policy="static"/>

    <reference name="DependencyBucket"
               bind="setDependencyBucket"
               unbind="unsetDependencyBucket"
               interface="com.company.product.common.DependencyBucket"
               cardinality="1..1"
               policy="static"/>

    <service>
        <provide interface="com.company.product.common.PayloadReadyNotifier"/>
        <provide interface="com.company.product.common.StateMachineXXXX"/>
        <!--<provide interface="com.company.product.common.ComponentStatusProvider"/>-->
    </service>

</component>
```

In other bundles which are activated successfully, there is an object listed under "Instances:" But this is not the case here.

I am confused as to why if "The component is satisfied" and "All component references are satisfied" why the ls command shows that the component is "Unsatisfied." Wondering how I might fix this! Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT: Looked in /var/log/kura-console.log and saw this:

```
ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.metatype 4 0 2018-05-02 21:03:45.009
!MESSAGE DataParser.finished() Missing element AD (Reference ID = com.company.product.dependencybucketimpl.DependencyBucketImpl.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.metatype 4 0 2018-05-02 21:03:45.018
!MESSAGE DataParser.finished() Object Class Definition ID not found com.company.product.dependencybucketimpl.DependencyBucketImpl.

!ENTRY com.company.product.dependencybucketimpl 4 0 2018-05-02 21:03:47.230
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.ServiceException: org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.ServiceReg.getService() returned a service object that is not an instance of the service class com.company.product.common.PayloadReadyNotifier
  at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceUse.getService(ServiceUse.java:174)
  at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.getService(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:468)
  at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.getService(ServiceRegistry.java:467)
  at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.getService(BundleContextImpl.java:594)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.getService(InstanceProcess.java:730)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ComponentReference.bind(ComponentReference.java:347)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.bindReference(ServiceComponentProp.java:446)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.dynamicBind(InstanceProcess.java:416)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:334)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
  at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
  at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
  at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
  at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
  at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
  at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry$1.run(ServiceRegistry.java:775)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:773)
  at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
  at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
  at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.registerService(InstanceProcess.java:536)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:213)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
  at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
  at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
  at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
  at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
  at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
  at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry$1.run(ServiceRegistry.java:775)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:773)
  at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
  at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
  at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.registerService(InstanceProcess.java:536)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:213)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.buildNewlySatisfied(Resolver.java:473)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.enableComponents(Resolver.java:217)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.performWork(SCRManager.java:816)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager$QueuedJob.dispatch(SCRManager.java:783)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.WorkThread.run(WorkThread.java:89)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.util.impl.tpt.threadpool.Executor.run(Executor.java:70)
```

The "Object Class Definition ID not found" bit here looks promising... I have double and triple checked case for the name of the package.

Followed by:

```
!ENTRY com.company.product.statemachineXXXXimpl 2 0 2018-05-02 21:03:47.284
!MESSAGE [SCR] Could not get the service object relevant to the reference. One possible reason is a circularity problem. Another possible reason is that BundleContext.getService() returns null.
  Details:
  Problematic reference = Reference[name = DependencyBucket, interface = com.company.product.common.DependencyBucket, policy = static, cardinality = 1..1, target = null, bind = setDependencyBucket, unbind = unsetDependencyBucket]
  of service component = com.company.product.statemachineXXXXimpl.StateMachineXXXXImpl
  component implementation class = com.company.product.statemachineXXXXimpl.StateMachineXXXXImpl
  located in bundle with symbolic name = com.company.product.statemachineXXXXimpl
  bundle location = osgi-dp:com.company.product.statemachineXXXXimpl

!ENTRY com.company.product.statemachineXXXXimpl 2 0 2018-05-02 21:03:47.286
!MESSAGE [SCR] ComponentReference.bind(): bind method 'setDependencyBucket' is not found or it is not accessible!
  Details:
  Problematic reference = Reference[name = DependencyBucket, interface = com.company.product.common.DependencyBucket, policy = static, cardinality = 1..1, target = null, bind = setDependencyBucket, unbind = unsetDependencyBucket]
  of service component = com.company.product.statemachineXXXXimpl.StateMachineXXXXImpl
  component implementation class = com.company.product.statemachineXXXXimpl.StateMachineXXXXImpl
  located in bundle with symbolic name = com.company.product.statemachineXXXXimpl
  bundle location = osgi-dp:com.company.product.statemachineXXXXimpl

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.ds 2 0 2018-05-02 21:03:47.291
!MESSAGE Could not bind a reference of component com.company.product.statemachineXXXXimpl.StateMachineXXXXImpl. The reference is: Reference[name = DependencyBucket, interface = com.company.product.common.DependencyBucket, policy = static, cardinality = 1..1, target = null, bind = setDependencyBucket, unbind = unsetDependencyBucket]

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.ds 4 0 2018-05-02 21:03:47.352
!MESSAGE The component was not built because some of its references could not be bound. The component is Component[
  name = com.company.product.statemachineXXXXimpl.StateMachineXXXXImpl
  activate = activate
  deactivate = deactivate
  modified = modified
  configuration-policy = optional
  factory = null
  autoenable = true
  immediate = true
  implementation = com.company.product.statemachineXXXXimpl.StateMachineXXXXImpl
  state = Unsatisfied
  properties = {service.pid=com.company.product.statemachineXXXXimpl.StateMachineXXXXImpl}
  serviceFactory = false
  serviceInterface = [com.company.product.common.StateMachineXXXX]
  references = {
    Reference[name = WatchdogService, interface = org.eclipse.kura.watchdog.WatchdogService, policy = static, cardinality = 1..1, target = null, bind = setWatchdogService, unbind = unsetWatchdogService]
    Reference[name = DependencyBucket, interface = com.company.product.common.DependencyBucket, policy = static, cardinality = 1..1, target = null, bind = setDependencyBucket, unbind = unsetDependencyBucket]
  }
  located in bundle = com.company.product.statemachineXXXXimpl_1.0.0.dev [92]
]
```

I am quite sure that the `setDependencyBucket` is implemented in the state machine implementation file, so I think the real snag is probably not in this block.

After removing the dependency on PayloadReadyNotifier some errors seem to be resolved. Remaining still are:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.metatype 4 0 2018-05-02 21:19:12.360
!MESSAGE DataParser.finished() Missing element AD (Reference ID = com.freewire.mobi.dependencybucketimpl.DependencyBucketImpl.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.metatype 4 0 2018-05-02 21:19:12.364
!MESSAGE DataParser.finished() Object Class Definition ID not found com.freewire.mobi.dependencybucketimpl.DependencyBucketImpl.
```

Feels close! Is this something wrong with the .xml perhaps?

EDIT #2: Added Component xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<component xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/scr/v1.1.0"
           name="com.company.product.dependencybucketimpl.DependencyBucketImpl"
           activate="activate"
           configuration-policy="optional"
           deactivate="deactivate"
           enabled="true"
           immediate="true"
           modified="modified">

    <implementation class="com.company.product.dependencybucketimpl.DependencyBucketImpl"/>

    <property name="service.pid"
              type="String"
              value="com.company.product.dependencybucketimpl.DependencyBucketImpl"/>

    <reference name="InverterManager"
               bind="setInverterManager"
               unbind="unsetInverterManager"
               interface="com.company.product.common.InverterManager"
               cardinality="1..1"
               policy="static"/>

    <reference name="BmsManager"
               bind="setBmsManager"
               unbind="unsetBmsManager"
               interface="com.company.product.common.BmsManager"
               cardinality="1..1"
               policy="static"/>

    <reference name="CanConnector"
               bind="setCanConnector"
               unbind="unsetCanConnector"
               interface="com.company.product.common.CanConnector"
               cardinality="1..1"
               policy="static"/>

    <reference name="ModbusManagerV1P2"
               bind="setModbusManagerV1P2"
               unbind="unsetModbusManagerV1P2"
               interface="com.company.product.common.ModbusManagerV1P2"
               cardinality="1..1"
               policy="static"/>

    <reference name="ModbusConnector"
               bind="setModbusConnector"
               unbind="unsetModbusConnector"
               interface="com.company.product.common.ModbusConnector"
               cardinality="1..1"
               policy="static"/>

    <reference name="GpioManagerL2Gen"
               bind="setGpioManagerL2Gen"
               unbind="unsetGpioManagerL2Gen"
               interface="com.company.product.common.GpioManagerL2Gen"
               cardinality="1..1"
               policy="static"/>

    <reference name="UnitConfiguration"
               bind="setUnitConfiguration"
               unbind="unsetUnitConfiguration"
               interface="com.company.product.common.UnitConfiguration"
               cardinality="1..1"
               policy="static"/>

    <service>
        <!--<provide interface="com.company.product.common.PayloadReadyNotifier"/>-->
        <provide interface="com.company.product.common.DependencyBucket"/>
        <!--<provide interface="com.company.product.common.ComponentStatusProvider"/>-->
    </service>

</component>
```

And the metatype:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<MetaData xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/metatype/v1.2.0"
          localization="en_us">

    <OCD id="com.company.product.dependencybucketimpl.DependencyBucketImpl"
         name="DependencyBucketImpl"
         description="">

    </OCD>

    <Designate pid="com.company.product.dependencybucketimpl.DependencyBucketImpl">
        <Object ocdref="com.company.product.dependencybucketimpl.DependencyBucketImpl"/>
    </Designate>
</MetaData>
```

Comment: This can sometimes happen if a runtime error is thrown when the bundle is starting. Can you try stopping/starting the bundle from the OSGi console and look for errors? You can also check /var/log/kura-console.log for any relevant errors.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! edits in response to your suggestion. Please let me know what you think!

Comment: Looks like a problem with the XML. I would make sure all of the XML elements are properly closed (ex: <AD></AD>). If possible, provide the component definition and metatype XML files.

Comment: More edits, thanks again!

Comment: Neil's point is valid. Also, I don't see any attribute definitions (i.e. <AD>) in your metatype file. Is that on purpose? Have a look at a metatype example from the Kura project: https://github.com/eclipse/kura/blob/develop/kura/examples/org.eclipse.kura.demo.heater/OSGI-INF/metatype/org.eclipse.kura.demo.heater.Heater.xml

Comment: You're not writing the Metatype XML by hand are you??

Comment: Err yes? Well actually I have metatype XML files that are already implemented, that I tweak when I want to make a new bundle. The double question marks suggest that you are surprised at this and have a better solution, I'm all ears!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error message is probably the root cause of all the others:

```
org.osgi.framework.ServiceException: org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.ServiceReg.getService() returned a service object that is not an instance of the service class com.company.product.common.PayloadReadyNotifier
```

You have not shown the code for the implementation class `com.company.product.statemachineXXXXimpl.StateMachineXXXXImpl`. But the error suggest that it does not implement or extend the type `com.company.product.common.PayloadReadyNotifier`, which you have declared as a service interface for the component.

When you publish an OSGi service, the implementation class must be castable to **all** of the service interfaces that you attempt to publish under.